# ttf monospace font nbsp spacing issue in Firefox and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, whitespace, spaces, monospace

On Chrome, everything works fine.  On Firefox and IE (IE is a .eot file, converted from the .ttf), I have character width problems for &nbsp and &#32.

Using the pre-defined monospace font, &nbsp displays in the proper width.  But if I use Ubuntu Mono or my own monospace truetype font, the space character is too narrow, and the text does not vertically align across line breaks.  It is as if it is using another font for the space character.

If I put an actual glyph into the space character (32 0x20), spacing is correct.  But once I remove the glyph and make the space character empty again, it reverts to faulty spacing. The example below uses Ubuntu Mono loaded from Google Fonts, so as to be useable by others. The letter "t", for example, should be aligned vertically.  The second example uses the built-in monospace font, and it looks fine.

HTML example #1:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>  
        <h1 style="font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono'; font-size: 200%;">
            &gt;In&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;___
        <br>&nbsp;One&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;+&nbsp;+&gt;
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;eaR&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;^&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;Out
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[=]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;the
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;~&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OtheR</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML example #2:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>  
        <h1 style="font-family: monospace; font-size: 200%;">
            &gt;In&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;___
        <br>&nbsp;One&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;+&nbsp;+&gt;
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;eaR&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;^&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;Out
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[=]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;the
        <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;~&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OtheR</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `<pre>` element solves my problem.  Pre-formatted text, it expects a monospace font and the spaces render in the correct width.  Bizarre, but true.  At least I found a solution.  I simply stick all this text in a `<pre>` instead of an `<h1>`.  Only thing that needs change is leading spaces, as `<pre>` does not ignore them.